# $M_{a} = \lbrace f \in R : f(a) = 0 \rbrace$ is a maximal ideal for the ring of every continuos functions $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is the ring of every continuos functions $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

For every $a\in [0,1]$, how I can proof that, the set

$M_{a} = \lbrace f \in R : f(a) = 0 \rbrace$ is a maximal ideal for R?

Comment: Have you been able to show it is an ideal at least? How much work have you  done?

Comment: Very similar to [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230974/i-fx-in-r-mid-f1-0-is-a-maximal-ideal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $a\in[0,1]$ and define $$R\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\\\ \ \ \ f\longmapsto f(a)$$
This map is a homomorphism surjective which kernel is $M_a$ (an ideal, in particular). So $R/M_a\simeq\mathbb{R}$ and therefore $M_a$ is maximal.

Answer (score 0):

We can directly prove that $M_{a}$ is maximal without using any theorems.

Let us take any ideal $N \supset M_{a}$ and we show that $N = R$. Clearly since $N \supset M_{a}$ there is an $f \in N$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$. Now let $g$ be any arbitrary member of $R$. Note that the function $h(x)$ given $$h(x) = g(x) - f(x)\cdot\frac{g(a)}{f(a)}$$ is continuous and hence $h \in R$. Also note that $h(a) = 0$ so that $h\in M_{a}\subset N$. It now follows that $g \in N$ as $g(x) = h(x) + f(x)g(a)/f(a)$.